# Можно ли упростить masterCheckbox/slaveCheckboxes

Tags: javascript, html

Можно ли улучшить указанный код, в смысле оптимизировать?

```
var masterCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][id="a"]');
var slaveCheckboxes1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id="a_a"]');
var slaveCheckboxes2 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id="a_b"]');
var slaveCheckboxes3 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id="a_b_a"]');

masterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (masterCheckbox.checked) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(slaveCheckboxes1, function (checkbox) {
      checkbox.checked = false;
      checkbox.disabled = true;
    });
  } else {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(slaveCheckboxes1, function (checkbox) {
      checkbox.disabled = false;
    });
  }
});
masterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (masterCheckbox.checked) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(slaveCheckboxes2, function (checkbox) {
      checkbox.checked = false;
      checkbox.disabled = true;
    });
  } else {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(slaveCheckboxes2, function (checkbox) {
      checkbox.disabled = false;
    });
  }
});
masterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (masterCheckbox.checked) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(slaveCheckboxes3, function (checkbox) {
      checkbox.checked = false;
      checkbox.disabled = true;
    });
  } else {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(slaveCheckboxes3, function (checkbox) {
      checkbox.disabled = false;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Почему именно конструкция `Array.prototype.forEach.call` ? Почему нельзя просто вызвать `.forEach`?

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, но меня больше интересует можно ли не использовать несколько `var slaveCheckboxes1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id="a_a"]');` а уложить это в одну?

Comment: Да, можно, обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

- Заменил `Array.prototype.forEach.call` на `.forEach`
- Объеденил все 3 ф-ии
- Условие не надо, т.к. при смене значения `masterCheckbox` у других значения становятся `false`
- Объеденил селектор для `slaveCheckboxes`

```
const masterCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][id="a"]');
const slaveCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id="a_a"], input[type="checkbox"][id="a_b"], input[type="checkbox"][id="a_b_a"]');

masterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  slaveCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    checkbox.disabled = masterCheckbox.checked;
  });
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137546/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer----mastercheckbox-slavecheckb).